# Digits of a number in Racket are in random order

Tags: recursion, racket, digit

I decided to write a function that given a number will return a list containing the digits in that number, my attempt is:

```
(define (rev-digits n)
  (if (= n 0)
    '()
    (cons (modulo n 10) (digits (quotient n 10)))))

(define (digits n)
  (reverse (rev-digits n)))
```

The fact is, I need the digits to be in proper order, but the function returns, for example:

```
> (digits 1234567890)
'(9 7 5 3 1 2 4 6 8 0)
```

In seemingly random order... can you help me getting a more ordinated output?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. The function works as expected and returns `'(0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)` for me. I am using DrRacket 5.2.1 on Windows.

Comment: @MarkusHimmel my bad, the code was not  complete, let me add more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rev-digits` needs to call itself, not `digits`.

```
(define (rev-digits n)
  (if (= n 0)
    '()
    (cons (modulo n 10) (rev-digits (quotient n 10)))))

(define (digits n)
  (reverse (rev-digits n)))
```

should work.

It's worth noting that your "random" output was not in fact random; rather the digits were "bouncing" back and forth from the start to the end of the list. Which makes sense, because you were effectively switching back and forth between a "normal" and reversed version of your digits function.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @JayKominek is spot-on and fixes the error in your code. To complement it, here's an alternative implementation:

```
(define (rev-digits n)
  (let loop ((n n) (acc '()))
    (if (< n 10)
        (cons n acc)
        (loop (quotient n 10) (cons (modulo n 10) acc)))))
```

The advantages of the above code are:

- It's tail recursive and hence more efficient
- It correctly handles the edge case when `n` is zero (your code returns an empty list)
- It doesn't require a helper procedure, thanks to the use of a named `let`
- It builds the list in the correct order, there's no need to `reverse` it at the end

Comment: @Caridorc check this alternative implementation

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
#lang racket
(define (digits n)
  (for/list ([c (number->string n)])
    (- (char->integer c) (char->integer #\0))))
```